# Australian visa for conference - invitation letter

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, australia, invitation-letters, conferences

I'm an Indian national who will be visiting Australia for a week to attend a conference. I am currently a graduate student in the UK. The conference organizers asked me what they should supply for the visa application.

As far as I understand, the visa category I should be applying for is https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/visitor-600/business-visitor-stream#HowTo. Under documents, it is quite vague and states that I need

> - an invitation from a host organisation
> - conference registration details
> - a letter from your employer stating why you are visiting
> - your plans for your stay and details of your Australian business contacts
> - proof of your current employment and professional qualifications
> - evidence your company is an active business, such as an annual report
> - evidence of prior contact with Australian businesses

Are there specific details that the conference hosts should include in my letter of invitation?

Comment: You don't need **all** of those, just those that are relevant to your situation. Many conference organisers already have a template for the invitation letter (some conferences even allow you to download it directly from their site or send it automatically to everybody).

Comment: @jcaron they don't have a template. They emailed me asking what should be in the letter. It's a small conference and I think I'm probably the only one that needs a visa

Comment: You'll find half a ton of samples and templates on Google. Make sure it contains the name of the conference, the dates, the location, who organises it, your name, the university you are from, the paper you will present and when, and that it includes contact info for the organizers if the consular officer wants to check. Print on letterhead paper, sign, scan, send.

Comment: You should get your conference organiser to contact the [International Event Coordinator Network](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/bringing-someone/bringing-for-activities/sponsoring-and-supporting/the-international-event-coordinator-network). They should be able to assist in preparing a properly formatted invitation letter.